# How to list the contents(files) of a search folder in listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

Here i have a problem, which is how to list the contents(files) of a search folder in listbox. The issue is i have many folder, each folder have many files with format .txt. I need, if i type the folder name in textbox and click the button, in the listbox shows all the files inside the search folder. In below i add my code, but it not works. Please help me....

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
    string search = TextBox1.Text; // here type the folder name
    if (search != "")
    //DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.123.1.18\Report\Result" + search);
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.123.1.16\Report\Result\"+ search + "*" + "*.*");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            //ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file), file));
            ListBox1.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(file), file)); // listed all files in the search folder
        }
        {
            search = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please Enter Search Keyword');</script>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.123.1.16\Report\Result\"+ search, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Thank You very much friend... it is work...i have another question, how to list the files into the listbox according to the date modified.... Please help me, because each folder have many files....

Comment: @T.Kumar as you noticed - it's another question, so according to rules of SO you should ask new question

Comment: Ok friend...By the way thanks for the code...it is really helpfull...;)